# Use custom on-screen keyboard form with OpenFileDialog and SaveFileDialog

Tags: winforms, on-screen-keyboard

We have a custom on-screen keyboard (OSK) form as part of our .NET Windows Forms Application.  This keyboard is useful to enter data into a `DataGridView` and some other textboxes.  We want to be able to use it to enter a file name into an `OpenFileDialog` or `SaveFileDialog`.

However, when either Dialog shows up, the form containing the OSK stops responding to input.  I tried creating a new `Form` that is used as the OSK's owner.  I use the new form and call `keyboard.Show(owner)`.  This still doesn't prevent the keyboard from being unable to be used while an `OpenFileDialog` or `SaveFileDialog` is in their `ShowDialog` method.

How can we use an on-screen keyboard form on top of an `OpenFileDialog` or `SaveFileDialog` without having the keyboard be hosted in a separate process?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, running the OSK window in another process *is* a fine idea.  You get it for free by running osk.exe, provided by Windows.   You could technically run it another STA thread but that's a fairly advanced technique, too many ways where the SystemEvents class can seriously ruin your life.

But you can solve the problem with a sliver of code, you just need to re-enable the OSK window right after the dialog is displayed.  Elegantly done with the BeginInvoke() method:

```
    private void OpenButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        this.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => EnableWindow(osk.Handle, true)));
        if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog(this) == DialogResult.OK) {
            // etc...
        }
    }

    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern bool EnableWindow(IntPtr hWnd, bool enable);
```

With the assumption that the `osk` variable stores a reference to your OSK form.